# How much should I care about prepared statements for simple queries?

Tags: postgresql, performance, prepared-statement, query-performance

I wonder how much I should care about prepared statements (and therefore try to optimize my code) in case of pretty simple statements.

The question originates from the fact that I recently noticed ActiveRecord (a Ruby ORM) writes different SQL queries depending on the way I chain the commands. Here's an example.

```
2.1.1 :004 > Account.first.domains.explain
  Account Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" ORDER BY "accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Domain Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."account_id" = $1  [["account_id", 1]]
 => EXPLAIN for: SELECT "domains".* FROM "domains"  WHERE "domains"."account_id" = $1 [["account_id", 1]]
                       QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on domains  (cost=0.00..1.35 rows=1 width=222)
   Filter: (account_id = 1)
(2 rows)
```

vs

```
2.1.1 :005 > Domain.for_account(Account.first).explain
  Account Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" ORDER BY "accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Domain Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."account_id" = 1
 => EXPLAIN for: SELECT "domains".* FROM "domains"  WHERE "domains"."account_id" = 1
                       QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on domains  (cost=0.00..1.35 rows=1 width=222)
   Filter: (account_id = 1)
(2 rows)
```

As you can see, the first statement generates a prepared statement, whereas the second one does not.

Is there a truly benefit in using prepared statements for such simple queries, or generally speaking the benefits I get in these cases are small enough to not justify major refactoring or workaround at code level?

Comment: It's dubious that the first statement is prepared, because the plan should show: `Filter: (account_id = $1)`. The point of a prepared statement is that the parameters values are not known at prepare/planning time.

Comment: @DanielV, thats not entirely the case. As of PostgreSQL 9.2 PostgreSQL may choose to produce a per-execution plan if it thinks it will be significantly faster to do so; check out GetCachedPlan in plancache.c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is negligible much of the time. You'll see significant benefits if:

- There are *lots* of joins or lots of predicates; or
- The query contains long `IN` lists or similar large data elements

In general, unless it's a "hot" code path where you really hammer a particular query   I wouldn't make much effort optimising to focus on re-usable prepared statements.

(You should still *parameterise* your SQL rather than substituting parameters directly into the text, and people often confuse that with *prepraed statements*, but you seem to understand the difference.)

Comment: The _parameterized_ query also having the benefit of additional security against such things as [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as well.

Comment: @JohnMcCall Hence my addendum that parameterising remains important; that doesn't mean you need re-usable prepared statements. Most people confuse the two, but it's possible to parameterise a query that's not a prepared statement, and you can (easily) fail to parameterise a prepared statement too.

Comment: Agreed - just wanted to make sure he understood some of the benefits of doing so.

Comment: When using JDBC a parameterized statement is always a prepared statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ... kind of. You always use the PreparedStatement interface. In PgJDBC it may or may not actually be prepared as a named, re-usable statement depending on the prepareThreshold and the number of times the statement has been executed. It always uses Parse/Bind/Describe/Execute but it initially doesn't ask the server to save the plan for re-use.